# How to fix "please insert disk into the drive" error with the Steam version of GTA 3?

Tags: pc, drm, grand-theft-auto-iii

I can't launch the game. The [Steam version](https://store.steampowered.com/app/12100/Grand_Theft_Auto_III/) obviously doesn't use physical disk and the error appears to be caused by leftover disk-check DRM.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install [CLEO library](http://cleo.li/) (for GTA 3).
I'm not aware how the protection is bypassed, but installing the program instantly fixed the issue.

[source](http://gtaforums.com/topic/877084-insert-disk-2/?p=1069315905)